# nodejs is it possible to have child process(fork) have the same context as parent

Tags: node.js

In nodejs is it possible to have child processs(fork) have the same context as parent. I would like to basically sandbox the current process into another current process ...and if there is an error in the child it just brings down the child process and parent process is still running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use the cluster API.  It's not exactly what you're describing, but pretty close.  Essentially, you have multiple child instances of the app running that can fail independently.

Answer (score 0):

It's my intuitive understanding that Nodejs doesn't actually fork() in the strict sense, it "spawns", execs, another instance of itself as a child process connected by IPC mechanisms. Why go through all this? Probably for cross platform uniformity, because Windows doesn't have a true fork. Yes, I know under Unix a "spawn" is a fork() then exec().

So the same process execs itself as a child, connected by IPC mechanisms, and within the code you branch based on whether you are the master (original process), or the child (worker). This is the cluster API. It's actually quite an ingenious, simple and straightforward solution.

That's just a guess. Someone can correct me if I'm wrong.

The cluster API will inform the master when a child dies and you can just-refork to restart the child. However, since this is not a real fork, you don't inherit file handles in the child process which I think is what you want.

Now, if you want, you can write your own C++ module for node. It's pretty simple, and you can do a real fork(). In fact I had to do just that because I needed a clustered UDP server and my primitive understanding of Nodejs at the time seemed to indicate you couldn't do that. Using a real fork confuses node in some peculiar ways, for me, the DNS functions would not work right, but that was the only problem I had. I think all the child forks were using the same UDP socket for DNS resolution and a DNS-request response intended for one worker would sometimes be eaten by a different worker.

If you are interested in that approach I can get you the code.